# Applescript - random number between

Tags: variables, random, applescript

Using Applescript I wish to randomly display a number between set range of number, like:

```
display dialog {random number between "100" , "250" , "310" , "356" , "401" ,}
```

Cannot understand how the "between" works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `"100"` is not a number it's a string.

`random number` can be used only when passing a start and end value in the `from` and `to` parameters, for example

```
set x to random number from 1 to 100
```

To get a random number from an arbitrary list of numbers use `some`

```
display dialog (some integer in {100, 250, 310, 356, 401}) as text
```